# Is there a way to execute a program on power events?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management, battery

I'm basically looking for a way to execute an application when my laptop transitions to battery power and, similarly, when it returns to AC.

Is there a built-in hook in Windows or a third-party application that will allow me to respond to such events?

**EDIT**

I've looked into the TaskScheduler trying to fire off a task on a "power" event, but no event seems to be logged when switching to battery.

Comment: Why do I have the sinking feeling that I'm going to need to write this app..

Comment: An app would work, but you might just need a script.

Comment: Hey man, I was about six years late to the party, but I think I've got something worth seeing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote an application (http://batterysaver.codeplex.com/) that will listen for a power mode change message and execute actions based on an XML configuration.

If someone else can use it, or extend it, then awesome.  If there's something better, then please post it.

Comment: As an enhancement, rather than polling GetSystemPowerStatus create an application to receive an WM_POWERBROADCAST messages that Windows sends when the power state changes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @shf301 - thanks for the tip; I updated it to respond to the power mode change event.

Comment: @RyanEmerle Nice app!

Comment: @RyanEmerle Agreed very nice app!

Comment: If I want to change battery profile in power events, what should I add in the config?

Comment: I think I can execute `powercfg` to change, but there is parameters, how to pass these parameters in config?

Comment: I missed the argument input and got it now, it seems working, thanks a lot for the tools.

Answer (score 5):

I love Bill's approach, but he doesn't tell you how to register for a WMI Event in PowerShell, so here's how to do it.

If you want your code to trigger only when the System Power State changes, [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394362(VS.85).aspx), use this code.

```
Register-WMIEvent -query "Select * From Win32_PowerManagementEvent" `
 -sourceIdentifier "Power" `
 -action {
     #YourCodeHere
      }
```

Now, this will trigger whenever the power state changes, whether you plug the device in, OR unplug it.  So you might further want to stop and pause to ask the question:

> Am I on power or not?

Fortunately we can do that via the WMI Class `BatteryStatus`, so here's the full construct that I use to ONLY run an operation when a power event changes, and then only if I'm no longer on Power.

```
Register-WMIEvent -query "Select * From Win32_PowerManagementEvent" `
  -sourceIdentifier "Power" `
  -action {
      if ([BOOL](Get-WmiObject -Class BatteryStatus -Namespace root\wmi).PowerOnLine ){
         #Device is plugged in now, do this action
         write-host "Power on!"
     }
    else{
        #Device is NOT plugged in now, do this action
        write-host "Now on battery, locking..."
        [NativeMethods]::LockWorkStation()
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't know of a simple command you can run for this, but scripting should be able to do this.

Try intercepting the [**Win32_PowerManagementEvent**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394362%28VS.85%29.aspx) event in [**PowerShell**](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/28/working-with-wmi-events.aspx) or [**WSH**](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/54297-45-batch-program-waking-standby). The tomshardware article has some vbscript code, but i think you'll need a case for eventtype 10 (powerstate change). StackOverflow has some ideas at [**How can I know when Windows is going into/out of sleep or Hibernate mode?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228288/how-can-i-know-when-windows-is-going-into-out-of-sleep-or-hibernate-mode), though you'll have to extend the idea to handle power state change instead of sleep/hibernate. You might also find some ideas in the code for the question [**How does one use ManagementEventWatcher to keep track of suspend/resume?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150502/how-does-one-use-managementeventwatcher-to-keep-track-of-suspend-resume)

EDIT: In fact, try something like this. This is totally hacked together, so it's not pretty. Change the Echo statements to do whatever you want if change to DC or AC power is detected. Run with `cscript power.vbs`

**power.vbs**

```
Dim battery_status, prev_status
prev_status = CheckBattery
Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")._
    ExecNotificationQuery("Select * from Win32_PowerManagementEvent")
Do
    Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    If strLatestEvent.EventType = 10 Then
        battery_status = CheckBattery
        If battery_status <> prev_status Then
            If battery_status = 1 Then
                Wscript.Echo "DC power"
            ElseIf battery_status = 2 Then
                Wscript.Echo "AC power"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    prev_status = battery_status
Loop

Function CheckBattery
    Dim oWMI, items, item
    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set items = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Battery",,48)
    For Each item in items
        If item.BatteryStatus = 1 Then
            CheckBattery = 1
            Exit Function
        ElseIf item.BatteryStatus = 2 then
        CheckBattery = 2
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: The idea is to start/stop applications when transitioning from one state to another to conserve battery power.  Therefore I don't want to defeat the purpose by running a heavy script (WMI is a bit heavy).

+1 for the detailed answer tho.

Comment: @Ryan - well, yeah. An application registering for WM_POWERBROADCAST approach is better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Combine Task Scheduler and Powershell to do this.

To achieve the Powershell script check out Chris85's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222256/1040683

Then create the Task in the Scheduler:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/6coxgp/how_to_run_a_task_when_plugged_into_ac_or_losing/