# Close programs when on battery

Tags: windows, automation, battery, power-management, battery-life

Is there a Windows application or a script that kills programs when my laptop in not plugged in (and preferably relaunches them when charging)?

I have a few background applications that use too many resources, and they are not really important, so they could be shut down when I'm using my laptop on battery.

Comment: Not on a laptop to confirm at the moment, but perhaps a scheduled task with a trigger on event? If there's an event when it switches to/from battery?

Comment: I'm guessing one might be able to write such a thing in PowerShell.  It has the ability to start and run background jobs, and to access the entire windows object model.  humm?

Comment: @Bob: Thanks, your idea and a few Superuser searches led me to a program which does exactly what I need (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the application BatterySaver in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/121118/284893), which does what I need, and even more (disabling devices, and services). You can download BatterySaver from [the project's page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126035642/http://batterysaver.codeplex.com/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126035642/http://batterysaver.codeplex.com/)).