# Is there a way to automatically quit two programs when battery is below certain level?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, autohotkey

I'm setting up a new laptop with Windows 7 and I'm using [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/) to display system info in a sidebar (CPU, memory, GPU info etc). This needs MSI Afterburner running in the background to access GPU stats.

Anyway, I realize all this extra software might be decreasing my battery life, so I'm looking for a way to automatically quit these two programs (Rainmeter and MSI) once battery is below a certain level (say 50%). I use Autohotkey for other things but haven't found a solution using that or any other program.

And ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that will close 2 processes after you've dropped below 50% battery.

```
SetTimer, CheckBatteryLevel, 2000
Return

CheckBatteryLevel:

    VarSetCapacity(powerstatus, 1+1+1+1+4+4)
    success := DllCall("kernel32.dll\GetSystemPowerStatus", "uint", &powerstatus)
    batteryLifePercent := ReadInteger(&powerstatus,2,1,false)

    if (batteryLifePercent < 50)
    {
        KillIfExists("Rainmeter.exe")
        KillIfExists("MSI.exe")
    }
    Return

KillIfExists(p)
{    
    Process, Exist, % p
    If (ErrorLevel)
        Process, Close, % p
}

ReadInteger( p_address, p_offset, p_size, p_hex=true )
{
    value = 0
    old_FormatInteger := a_FormatInteger
    if ( p_hex )
    SetFormat, integer, hex
    else
    SetFormat, integer, dec
    loop, %p_size%
    value := value+( *( ( p_address+p_offset )+( a_Index-1 ) ) << ( 8* ( a_Index-1 ) ) )
    SetFormat, integer, %old_FormatInteger%
    return, value
}
```

I modified the code found in [this post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7022-acbattery-status/)

Comment: wow.. excellent answer. Thanks for the help. I saw that post in my original search but my programming skill isn't (yet) up to the task of completing the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this one out. http://batterysaver.codeplex.com/
Gives you the ability to kill processes based on a battery decrease.
The program is in early stages of development and isn't very user friendly, however it can still get the job done and kudos to [Ryan Emerly](https://superuser.com/users/30269/ryan-emerle) for his hard work on deveolopment. You will have to run the program as administrator and play around with it a bit to get it working.

Source: [Is there a way to execute a program on power events?](https://superuser.com/questions/121045/is-there-a-way-to-execute-a-program-on-power-events)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to Rainmeter.
I have not tested it, but [this](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/plugins/power/) plugin can measure battery percentage.
You could create a skin that uses `if` to measure when battery drops below a certain percent, and then opens an exe, which would be an Autohotkey program to close Rainmeter.

I am aware this question is old, but I thought I will add my two cents for anyone who has the same question. I have not tested it, but I see no reason it shouldn't work.